# specific get methods or general get method?

Tags: java

In some programming API's I see a list of methods to call, like getBoolean(String key, getDouble(String key), and getString(String key). Some other API's use a general get(String key) method, and return an Object which you are supposed to cast to an appropriate type yourself.

Now I am writing my own data accessing point, and I am wondering which approach to use. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach? When would you choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advantage: getBoolean(), getDouble(), etc. allow you to return the respective primitive types. As far as I've seen, that's the primary reason anyone writes methods like that.

Comment: Why would this be an advantage? Modern Java versions use autoboxing, so the difference between Integer and int can be largely ignored (according to [Java documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)). Is it still worth the trouble?

Comment: Primitive types should always be preferred to wrappers. Maybe the most compelling reason: what is the result of `new Long(1).equals(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Provide getters for the types that are most likely to be used. There's no real right or wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the purpose of the library. When the output is a predictable set of items, then toy can have specific names. As in [ResultSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).
If it is generic, then you will need generic get methods. Like [ObjectOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)

In a very high level sense, you might need both: `getBoolean`, `getDouble`, `getIngeter` for the primitives (or their respective wrappers), a `getString`, for `Strings` and a generic `get` or a `getObject` for getting out objects.

However, this is a very generic answer for a very generic questions. What your tries to do very much decided such stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Two questions:
1) Why don't you use general Properties instead, à là:

```
String getName()
Address getAddress()
Date getDateOfBirth()
```

etc?

2) If you want to use methods like:

```
String getString(String key)
Double getDouble(String key)
Address getAddress(String key)
```

How on earth would I, as the user, know, which key's are associated with objects of type String, which are associated with objects of type Double, etc?

I would recommend going with a solution similar to 1).
If I didn't misunderstand your question, that is.

Comment: Answer to question 1: most of my methods do the same thing internally (communicating to a web API, handling exceptions), but are slightly different. Combining them in one method decreases code duplication. Answer to question 2: Well, if you (as the user), wouldn't know, how am I to use the ResultSet Java class then? I am wondering why API's are using this at all.. :)

Comment: To answer your question under option 2, just look at the [JDBC ResultSet API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). Quite often you, as the user, know more about the data you're requesting than a generic data holder does. Aside from that, the data could be representable in multiple formats. All other things being equal, I would choose an API that does those things for me over one that doesn't.